# Do Kubernetes service IPs change?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm very new to kubernetes/docker, so apologies if this is a silly question.

I have a pod that is accessing a few services. In my container I'm running a python script and need to access the service. Currently I'm doing this using the services' IP addresses.

Is the service IP address stable or is it better to use [environment variables](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#environment-variables)? If so, some tips on doing that would be great.

The opening paragraph of the [Services Documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/) gives a motivation for services which implies stable IP addresses, but I never see it explicitly stated:

> While each Pod gets its own IP address, **even those IP addresses cannot be relied upon to be stable over time**. This leads to a problem: if some set of Pods (let’s call them backends) provides functionality to other Pods (let’s call them frontends) inside the Kubernetes cluster, how do those frontends find out and keep track of which backends are in that set?
>
> Enter Services.

My pod spec for reference:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fetchdataiso 
  labels:
    name: fetchdataiso
spec:
  containers:
    - name: fetchdataiso 
      image: 192.111.1.11:5000/ncllc/fetch_data
      command: ["python"]
      args: ["feed/fetch_data.py", "-hf", "10.222.222.51", "-pf", "8880", "-hi", "10.223.222.173", "-pi","9101"]
```

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is "Yes, the service IP can change"

```
$ kubectl apply -f test.svc.yml
service "test" created

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   10.12.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   10d
test         10.12.172.156   <none>        80/TCP    6s

$ kubectl delete svc test
service "test" deleted

$ kubectl apply -f test.svc.yml
service "test" created

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   10.12.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   10d
test         10.12.254.241   <none>        80/TCP    3s
```

The long answer is that if you use it right, you will have no problem with it. What is even more important in scope of your question is that ENV variables are way worse then DNS/IP coupling.
You should refer to your service by **service** or **service.namespace** or even full path like something along the lines of **test.default.svc.cluster.local**. This will get resolved to service ClusterIP, and in opposite to your ENVs it can get re-resolved to a new IP (which will probably never happen unless you explicitly delete and recreate service) while ENV of a running process will not be changed

Comment: I think the point is that the service IP will remain stable until you decide to delete/recreate it. But I do agree that using the dns name is better.

Comment: Is there a better way for service discovery in this case (service restarts) than DNS (where clients can cache older entries)?

Comment: @prat0318 in fact this is a very rare case, usually you would go with `apply` rather then `delete` and `create` as in my example. Because of that kubernetes service discovery is quite powerfull (when you change underlying pods, their IP change, but you are still pointed to clusterIP that did not change at all)

Answer (score 0):

The service IP address is stable. You should only need to use environment variables if you don't have a better way of discovering the IP address (e.g. DNS).

Comment: Thanks, a link to the documentation would be super helpful. My boss doesn't believe me! I tried replacing the IP addresses in my args with the environment variables, for example: "$IQFEED_SERVICE_HOST" but the pods just kept crashing. What would be the proper way to access them? I know the environment variables exist because I logged into a running container and ran echo $IQFEED_SERVICE_HOST which displayed the IP.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the DNS cluster addon within your cluster to access your services, and your service is called `foo` in namespace `bar`, you can also access it as `bar.foo`, which is likely more meaningful than a plain IP address.

See http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#dns

Comment: Thanks. How would I use that in my pod spec? I have two namespaces **kube-system** and **default**. My service name is **ssdb-feed**. So would I pass ssdb-feed.kube-system in place of the IP address? I tried that and the pod crashes.

Comment: @Shuaib Your service is probably in the default namespace. Just passing in `ssdb-feed` should work, as long as your pods are in the same namespace. If you want to verify, you can run a busybox pod and try to resolve the name of the service from within the cluster.