# Service discovery in case of kubernetes service recreation/restarts

Tags: service, dns, kubernetes, service-discovery

It is a followup question to an earlier asked [SO question regarding stability of serviceIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650010/do-kubernetes-service-ips-change). I understand that in general, serviceIP are stable, but my case is the one where service [gets often restarted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39656020), like for port changes.

using DNS is not the perfect solution in this case as client pods can cache the DNS entry. So, i wanted to know the best practice around this.

Answer (score 0):

The service IP can be defined as a fixed IP by setting the `spec.clusterIP` field.

The IP address that a user chooses must be a valid IP address and within the `service-cluster-ip-range`.

It would be recommended to either use automatic IP addresses for all services or manage the service IPs of all services manually.

For more info please see the [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#choosing-your-own-ip-address).